# Dynamically combine classes in order to remove responsibilities from API

Tags: c#, api, system.reflection

I'm building an API (for a game-engine) which exposes two interfaces called `IWindow` and `IEngineWindow`.

The `IWindow` interface is supposed to be implemented by an API-user and the `IEngineWindow` interface is used by the engine to interact with the window.

The window object should have a private member of the type `List<IWindowControl>`.
I could use an abstract class and get rid of the interfaces but then i would have implementation-details in my API which i don't want.

My theoretical solution to the problem is that the API-user implements IWindow in his own class and calls a method (something like `GetEngineWindow(typeof(MyWindowClass))`) which returns an object which is identical to an instance of `MyWindowClass` except that it also implements the `IEngineWindow` interface.

I was planning to use `System.Reflection.Emit` in the `GetEngineWindow()` method to dynamically combine `MyWindowClass` with an internal class which implements the `IEngineWindow` interface but i quickly realised that this would be a mayor project of it's own.

My question boils down to if there is a simpler solution to remove this kind of implementation-details from an API or if there exists a library (free for commercial use) to do this kind of class-fusing.

In case my question is too abstract, here is a code example of what i want to be able to do:

```
//API (dll-file)
interface IWindow
{
    void BeforeClose();
}

interface IEngineWindow
{
    void Show();
}

//Built into engine (written by me)
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object window = CombineClasses(typeof(Testwindow), typeof(EngineWindow));
        ((IWindow)window).BeforeClose(); //Outputs: Closing...
        ((IEngineWindow)window).Show();  //Outputs: Showing window...
    }
}

class EngineWindow : IEngineWindow
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Showing window...");
    }
}

//External assembly (dll-file)
class Testwindow : IWindow
{
    public void BeforeClose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you need a wrapper.

- Let your internal class take an `IWindow` instance in its constructor
- store it in a private field
- implement both interfaces
- and forward all `IWindow` members to the internal instance

**Update**: if you consider [CastleWindsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) a simpler approach, here it is (using [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/) for tests):

```
namespace Mixins
{
    using System;
    using Castle.DynamicProxy;
    using Xunit;

    public interface IA
    {
        void Do();
    }

    public interface IB
    {
        void Something();
    }

    public class A : IA
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("A");
        }
    }

    public class B : IB
    {
        public void Something()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("B");
        }
    }

    public class Blender
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Mix()
        {
            var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
            // the instances for A and B would be the user provided and yours
            options.AddMixinInstance(new A());
            options.AddMixinInstance(new B());
            var proxy = new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxy<object>(options);

            Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IA>(proxy);
            Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IB>(proxy);

            try
            {
                ((IA)proxy).Do();
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message != "A")
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                ((IB)proxy).Something();
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message != "B")
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a feasible solution but i would like to know if there is a simpler way to do the class-fusing for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX see my edited answer for a different (I wouldn't say simpler :-) approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [NCop](https://github.com/sagifogel/NCop) - A composite-aspect framework that can help you achieve your goal.
[NCop wiki](https://github.com/sagifogel/NCop/wiki)
You basically need to create a new composite type interface that will implement both of your window interfaces and mark it as a composite using the `TransientComposite` attribute.

```
[TransientComposite]
public interface ICompositeWindow : IWindow, IEngineWindow
{
}
```

Order NCop to match between interfaces and implementations using `Mixins` attribute.

```
[TransientComposite]
[Mixins(typeof(EngineWindow), typeof(Testwindow))]
public interface ICompositeWindow : IWindow, IEngineWindow
{
}
```

create a `CompositeContainer` that will emit the new type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ICompositeWindow window = null;
        var container = new CompositeContainer();

        container.Configure();
        window = container.Resolve<ICompositeWindow>();
        window.Show();
        window.BeforeClose();
    }
}
```

your final code should be:

```
using System;
using NCop.Composite.Framework;
using NCop.Mixins.Framework;
using NCop.Composite.Runtime;

namespace NCop.Samples
{
    [TransientComposite]
    [Mixins(typeof(EngineWindow), typeof(Testwindow))]
    public interface ICompositeWindow : IWindow, IEngineWindow
    {
    }

    public interface IWindow
    {
        void BeforeClose();
    }

    public interface IEngineWindow
    {
        void Show();
    }

    public class EngineWindow : IEngineWindow
    {
        public void Show() {
            Console.WriteLine("Showing window...");
        }
    }

    public class Testwindow : IWindow
    {
        public void BeforeClose() {
            Console.WriteLine("Closing...");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ICompositeWindow window = null;
            var container = new CompositeContainer();

            container.Configure();
            window = container.Resolve<ICompositeWindow>();
            window.Show();
            window.BeforeClose();
        }
    }
}
```